# Visual Studio 2015: Create an Empty Project

Tags: c#, ide, visual-studio-2015

Where is the Empty Project option within VS 2015?

There is no longer a "General" or "Other templates" category & is not visible under the basic list of C#/C++ options.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The "Empty Project" *template* (if it can be called that) is now located under:

***Installed → Visual (C#/C++/etc) → Windows → Classic Desktop***

**Empty Project** will show up as a standard item within the alphabetically ordered list.

This is assuming you installed basic language templates when installing VS - otherwise, just pick your language & follow the prompts to install the necessary tools (+templates).

Comment: I cant believe its embedded so deep down the menus man, it really should be a top level option!

Answer (score 0):

You can search too, it's quicker (VS2015): 
File > New > Project > [*Search Installed Templates* Empty] > Blank Solution.

For me it's the first solution choice.